# combinedStream not same checksum on join parts of chunk nodejs

Tags: node.js, cat

I am using nodeJs to concatinate multiple chunks of 1 MB files. The Linux cat command works:

```
cat /tmp/part.* >> /tmp/full
```

Using the following does gives an other sha256 checksum:

```
//At this point /tmp/full non existing.
for(var i = 0; i &lt; 5; i++) {
  var combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();
  combinedStream.append(fs.createReadStream("/tmp/part."+i));
  combinedStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/full", {'flags': 'a'}));
}
```

I also tested with spawnSync, but I get a strange error:

```
var cat = require('child_process').spawnSync("/bin/cat", ["/tmp/part.1", ">>", "tmp/full"]);
console.log(cat.status );
console.log(cat.stderr.toString());
console.log(cat.error);
```

Output:

```
1
/bin/cat: >>: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: tmp/full: No such file or directory

undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?